# Implicit Function Theorem (Two Variables)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, implicit-function-theorem

While reading through a paper I came a cross a result (due to the Implicit Function Theorem) that I cannot derive.

Let $u(x,y)$ be the solution of a PDE ($x$ and $y$ are independent variables). We can expand the solution around an arbitrary non-characteristic singularity manifold given by $g(x,y)=0$ in a power series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(x,y)g(x,y)^{n+\alpha},$ where $\alpha$ is a negative integer (to be found using leading order analysis).

The following result is the one that I cannot derive.

---

Given that $g=0$ is assumed to be non-characteristic we have $g_{y}\neq 0$. Thus, by the Implicit Function Theorem we have $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$ near $g=0$, where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.

---

How do I get $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$ near $g=0$?

Comment: $f$ isn't arbitrary in the theorem. You could consider re-reading the statement of the IFT to get the answer to your question.

Comment: Dear @InTransit, Thanks for your comment. I think I got it. By the IFT, $y=f(x)$ near $g=0$. This means that $y-f(x)=0$ near $g=0$. So, we can let $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$. Is this right? Somehow, I overlooked this :-). Thanks, once again.